# How to set order of sorting MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)

col_num = 1
row_num = 18
col_names = ['C' + str(x) for x in range(col_num)]

mix = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a', 'b'], [ '01 Jan 2011', '02 Feb 2000', '30 Apr 1999'], [1,2,3]])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(((np.random.rand(row_num,col_num)* 2 - 1)*100),2), columns = col_names, index = mix)
```

```
#df
                    C0
a 01 Jan 2011 1  39.29
              2 -42.77
              3 -54.63
  02 Feb 2000 1  10.26
              2  43.89
              3 -15.38
  30 Apr 1999 1  96.15
              2  36.97
              3  -3.81
b 01 Jan 2011 1 -21.58
              2 -31.36
              3  45.81
  02 Feb 2000 1 -12.29
              2 -88.06
              3 -20.39
  30 Apr 1999 1  47.60
              2 -63.50
              3 -64.91
```

How to sort MultiIndex in such a way that dates on level 1 are kept in chronological order while preserving sorting on other mix levels as is, including priority of levels ordering (ie: first level 0, then level1 and finally level2).

I need to keep dates as strings in final df. Final df will be pickled. I try to set sorting order of dates before serializing rather than writing sorting function after retrieving df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create a new `MultiIndex` after setting the `level 1` values mapped to `datetime` then use `argsort` on this new index to get the indices that would sort the original dataframe:

```
idx = df.index.set_levels(pd.to_datetime(df.index.levels[1]), 1)
df1 = df.iloc[np.argsort(idx)]
```

---

```
print(df1)
                     C0
a 30 Apr 1999  1  96.15
               2  36.97
               3  -3.81
  02 Feb 2000  1  10.26
               2  43.89
               3 -15.38
  01 Jan 2011  1  39.29
               2 -42.77
               3 -54.63
b 30 Apr 1999  1  47.60
               2 -63.50
               3 -64.91
  02 Feb 2000  1 -12.29
               2 -88.06
               3 -20.39
  01 Jan 2011  1 -21.58
               2 -31.36
               3  45.81
```

Comment: Beautiful. It works and level1 order is preserved through pickling. Of course sorting index will revert that process. I will try to play with categories but this will do. Thank you very much Shubham Sharma.

Comment: @Ranny Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

If one wants to create desired df with sorted index and doesn't mind having categorical index, here is a code to achieve it (probably there is a simpler way but I couldn't find it :).

Start with df from question above.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
```

```
org_l1 = df.index.get_level_values(1).unique().tolist()

l1_as_date = [dt.strptime(x, '%d %b %Y') for x in org_level1]

l1_as_date.sort()

l1_sorted_as_str = [dt.strftime(x, '%d %b %Y') for x in l1_as_date]

df= df.reset_index()
df.level_1 = df.level_1.astype('category')
df.level_1 = df.level_1.cat.set_categories(l1_sorted_as_str, ordered=True)
df = df.set_index(['level_0', 'level_1', 'level_2'])
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```